# Entity Framework Clone List

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using a IEnumerable which I have saved in the cache. I need a copy of this list and transform the contents. This copy is temporary and is not saved.

Currently I am using IClonable on MyObject to create a new list. This works but causes EF to take a second trip to the database, thus its very slow. How can I clone this list without EF going to the database? The data is already in memory in the cache.

Alternatively; is there a better way to copy the list from cache so I can temporarily use it?

Using EF5, .Net 4.5.

This is what I use to clone. Note that residualList is in the cache. But this line still causes EF to get everything from the database.

`var clonedList = residualList.Select(x => (Product) x.Clone()).ToList();`

Comment: several solutions: detach the list from the context or use the Local property of the DbSet, or serialize the List and unserialize for duplication. BTW this sounds like residualList is a IQueryable or a DbQuery, it should not in your use case.

Comment: residualList is a List<MyObject> (created from dbContext with the .ToList() method so should be in memory). Ill try your suggestions in the morning, thanks.

Comment: in this case may be tle Clone method fires some virtual properties and you are facing a [n+1 select issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/97197/what-is-the-n1-selects-issue)